# What does "Having gained truth, keep truth" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

**Having gained truth, keep truth.**

What the sentence express??

Comment: You need to give some more details.  Firstly, who wrote this?  Where did you read this? Next, tell us what your difficulty is?  Do you know the meaning of the word "truth",  or "keep"?  Are you unsure what "having ..." means?  Do you know what "Keep truth" would mean on its own.  Would you understand if a different word like "Money" was used instead of "truth"...  More details please!

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521859/perfect-participle-having-gained-truth-keep-truth  Apparently this is Wren and Martin example sentence.   (Don't use this book, it is a bad book)

Comment: @JamesK it's a bad book! In terms of what???

Comment: It does not teach correct, modern English.  It has confusing examples.  It is wrong about English grammar in many ways. It is a bad book for learning English as a non-native speaker because it was not written for learning English.

Comment: ... and it contains spelling mistakes. See the last word of example 12: "terriroty".

Comment: There's probably an echo of the expression "to keep true (to something)" which means to remain faithful. Although Astralbee's answer gives the basic meaning.

Comment: @StuartF It may mean if you have get the quality of being true, then stay in that condition(remains true always)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Gaining* something is the process of obtaining it.

*Keeping* something means retaining it.

For example, you could earn money, and then save it in a bank. You've gained it, and then kept it.

Gaining and keeping 'truth' is more of an abstract concept. Personally, I would interpret it to mean that there exists a pursuit of truth, and having learned something to be true, you should 'hold' onto that - not simply 'remembering' what you learned, but living by it, using it in your life. To be honest, it sounds like a generic 'inspirational' quote, and a little pseudo-spiritual - the sort of thing that can mean all things to all people, and perhaps you are meant to read your own meaning into it anyway.